# Run Python script out of python script via .bat

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have created a python script e.g. `HelloWorld.py`.

Within this script it calls a second script `GoodMorning.py` via `exec(open("GoodMorning.py").read())`.

I have now created a `.bat` file to run my `HelloWorld.py`.

```
"C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" "C:\Users\myself\Desktop\Test\HelloWorld.py"
pause
```

if I start the .bat file now it returns the error `no such file or directory: GoodMorning.py`

How can this be adjusted in order for the `HelloWorld.py` script to properly be able to start the `GoodMorning.py` script at the correct moment?

Do I have do make an adjustment in my `HelloWorld.py` script or the `.bat` file?

Comment: Running Python from Python is almost never a good idea. Refactor the code in the second script so you can `import` it. If you need them to run in parallel, look into `multiprocessing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are HelloWorld.py and GoodMorning.py in the same folder?

I'm not 100% sure, but looks like the problem is that you use a *relative path* to GoodMorning.py instead of an *absolute path* like "C:\Users\myself\Desktop\Test\GoodMorning.py", and your script tries to find GoodMorning.py in the *current working directory* (from where you execute the .bat script) instead of the directory where HelloWorld.py is. If that's the case, you have two options:

- Use an absolute path to GoodMorning.py. This is a very fragile solution, it only works if no one else would ever install your script to a different folder than "C:\Users\myself\Desktop\Test".

  By the way, your .bat script is already very fragile, because it assumes your username and Python version ("C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe"). It's better to add Python to PATH, and than in your script just call it as "python.exe".
- In your .bat script or HelloWorld.py, automatically change the current working directory to the location of HelloWorld.py before executing GoodMorning.py. This solution is more reliable, but a bit harder to code.

Comment: hi @Expurple,thanks for your input. This is just for me to "play around" so no potential usage on others. I managed to find a solution by changing the directory within the batch scrip.